# Display count of selected options using ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng-select component to allow users to select multiple options from a list.

When 1 option is selected I want the option to be visible like normal. But, when 2 or more options are selected I want my custom template to display a summary like `2 Selected`.  Visual example:

[image: Visual Example]

My attempt at the custom layout in the template code is this:

```
  <ng-template ng-multi-label-tmp let-items="items" let-clear="clear">
    <div *ngIf="selectedCounter >= 1" class="ng-values-list">
      <div class="ng-value" *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:1">
        <span class="ng-value-label">{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)">×</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="selectedCounter > 1" class="ng-summary-list">
      <div class="ng-value">
        <span class="ng-value-label">{{ selectedCounter }} Selected</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Which currently shows both the selected option, **and** the summary like this:

[image: Example of problem]

Is there anything I can do inside the template code to show only the summary when there is more than 1 option selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the first div be :

```
    <div *ngIf="selectedCounter == 1" class="ng-values-list">
```

when selectedCounter = 2 both your if are true.